# How to get production configuration variables when executing in another environment

Tags: configuration, laravel, laravel-4, environments

In laravel configuration variables can be accessed like this

```
   Config::get('xxx')
```

By default it returns the configuration values for the current environment. How do you get configuration data for other environments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A call to `Config::get()` will already get you information of your current environment, if you are in dev it will be dev, if you are in production it will be the production data.

If you need to get a configuration information about another environment you can do by:

```
return Config::get('environment/config.name');
```

Example:

```
return Config::get('testing/cache.driver');
```

If you need to get things from your production environment while being in any other one, I'm afraid you'll have to create a 'production' folder inside your config folder and put those things there:

```
app/config/production/database.php
```

Add to that particular file only what you need to read outside from your environment:

```
'default' => 'postgresql',
```

And then you'll have access to it:

```
return Config::get('production/database.default');
```

Comment: Config::get('environment/config.name') seems to work for everything except production. How do I get a production-value when I'm in local environment?

Comment: I won't judge what you are doing, but your question already started to look wrong, but now it's getting worse, to me looking from the outside. Why would you have to access production information from your testing development environment? Your environments should not even be aware of their existence. If it's something that is available to both environments, somehow, is this really the right place to put them? Anyway I'm just answering and I just edited to show a way to access it.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just do `Config::get('xxx');`

Unless you are overriding it in your testing/local/develop environments it should always be available.  If you are, just remove it from the other envs.

I cannot see why you would define a config variable in another environment but then still need the production config.

Comment: my scenario. I'm in my vagrant box, i want to copy over the production db. I could hardcode the production db name in my command, but this doesn't feel right.